# Jobs stopped in celluloid pool

Tags: ruby, redis, celluloid

Im need to retrieve data for account in parallel. I use celluloid for that

my code

```rb
class Daemon

  def self.start
    loop do
       Account.all.each do |acc|
         unless Celluloid::Actor[account.name]
          supervise_as(account.name, account)
          Celluloid::Actor[account.name].async(:perform)
        end

        sleep 10.minutes
      end
    end

    def initialize(account)
      @account = account
    end

    def perform
      loop do
        do_request

        sleep 10
      end
    end
  end
```

On start it always do parallel request for all members(bob, alice, etc).
But after some time it makes requests only for one user (alice for ex.)

PS in `do_request` used self-made redis queue
and in `Celluloid::Actor.registed` all accounts exists